# Хранилище для графа

Tags: java, база-данных, графы

Мне необходимо хранить, обновлять и отдавать по запросу некоторые элементы графа. Под графом в данном случае я подразумеваю его представление в таблице вида **КЛЮЧ**->**МАССИВ_ЗНАЧЕНИЙ** и таблице вершин, где у каждой вершины есть своё значение в виде вектора чисел. Если метрика схожести (cosine similarity) между двумя вершинами (A и B, например) больше порогового значения, то каждая из вершин добавляется в таблицу с ключами и значениями (B добавляется к A, а A добавляется к B).

Под обновлением я подразумеваю то, что раз в какое-то время в граф будет попадать новые вершины и нужно будет перестраивать граф (возможно, новая вершина достаточно похожа на какую-то из старых и их нужно "объединить" в первой таблице).

Под отдачей по запросу я подразумеваю то, что такое хранилище должно отдавать значения из первой таблицы по запросу. Например, мне нужны вершины, похожие на вершину с ID=1. Тогда я делаю запрос, условно, "SELECT ID=1" и мне возвращаются нужные вершины.

Есть ли готовое решение для этой задачи? Основное приложение на Java

Comment: Прям конкретно под вашу задачу я готовых решений не знаю, но существуют специализированные [графовые базы данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85), заточенные именно под хранение графов и поиск в них. Коннекторы для Java точно есть для neo4j и OrientDB, за остальные ручаться не могу.

Comment: @fori1ton, есть ли возможность в одном из этих инструментов добавить автоматическое обновление графов, как я описал в посте?

Comment: а метрика постоянная - или порог может меняться? если порог может менятся то данные получается каждый раз надо пересчитывать

Comment: @dSH, порог постоянный. Ну, мб и придётся его поменять, но это будет еще не скоро

Comment: не совсем понимаю зачем готовое какое-то решение искать - взяли обычную БД - например Postgres - и реализовали процедуру добавления новой вершины в граф.

Comment: @vladF, Нет, это просто БД, которые просто хранят информацию. Любая логика реализуется в приложении, которое использует эту БД.

Comment: @dSH дело в скорости. Сейчас как раз реализовано всё в Postgres, но получается так, что происходит слишком много обновлений графа, слишком много запросов, и как результат - высокая нагрузка на диск

Comment: @fori1ton, очень жаль в таком случае. Но спасибо

Comment: Попробуйте сохранять в БД пакетами а не по одной вершине, и/или возьмите БД типа Redis, и/или сохраняйте сначала вершины которые нужно вставить, а потом фоном пересчитывайте соседей. В любом случае если данные критичны к потере  вам придется их на диск записывать хотя бы в виде журнала. А если нет, то тут широкое поле возможностей. Просто все зависит от требований, которые выставляет "клиент" этой БД.